# Parse any JSON to JValue without specifying a case class

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I try to explain better.

I am parsing a json file from a json String such as:

```
[
 {
   "album": "The White Stripes",
   "year": 1999,
   "US_peak_chart_post": 55
 },
 {
   "album": "De Stijl",
   "year": 2000,
   "US_peak_chart_post": 66
 }
]
```

to a `Seq[Album]`:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

object AlbumsHandler{
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

    def extractAlbumsFromJsonFile(json: String): Seq[Album] = {

      val jValues: Try[JValue] = Try(parse(json))
      val albums: Seq[Album] = jValues.map(
        value => value.extract[Seq[Album]]
      ).getOrElse(Seq())

      albums
    }
}
```

by providing a `case class` of `Album` as a "BluePrint":

```
case class Album(album: String, year: Int, US_peak_chart_post: Int)
```

Is there a way to do the same thing I am already doing, extracting a `Seq[Album]` from my JSON, but automatically, without having to specify a `case class` as a blueprint?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, any JSON object can be extracted into a `Map`, and any JSON array can be extracted into a `Seq`. However, it's not too convenient to work with `Map[String, Any]`, and there's no way simpler than specifying a case class to extract a typesafe structure.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val json = """[
             | {
             |   "album": "The White Stripes",
             |   "year": 1999,
             |   "US_peak_chart_post": 55
             | },
             | {
             |   "album": "De Stijl",
             |   "year": 2000,
             |   "US_peak_chart_post": 66
             | }
             |]""".stripMargin

val map = parse(json).extract[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]
// map: Seq[Map[String,Any]] = List(Map(album -> The White Stripes, year -> 1999, US_peak_chart_post -> 55), Map(album -> De Stijl, year -> 2000, US_peak_chart_post -> 66))
```

Comment: Thanks. And how to get an Album class as a result, or any other class?

Comment: Isn't _not_ getting `Album` class as a result what you wanted to achieve? Your version with the case class was correct if you wanted the entity.

Comment: Yes, you are correct; but my problem is that I would like to have as little coupled code as possible. Therefore I would like having a method being able to extract a json and at the same time being able to reused to obtain objects for other classes as well as for Album.

Comment: It's probably not the best idea to return an untyped `Map[String, Any]` just to reduce the amount of exported code... And you'd need to manually define a constructor for `Album` taking in a `Map`.

Comment: So what would the best solution be?

Comment: In my opinion, there's nothing wrong with shipping `case class Album` along with the method to extract one from a JSON. If, for example, you have two subprojects both of which need to refer to `Album` but do not need to depend on one another, just extract the model (and the json parser) into another "core" or "commons" project and make your subprojects depend on it.